# Python Class Inheritance: Recursion Error

Tags: python

I'm trying to wrap my head around classes and I don't see what I have done wrong in this script.  I have built a few nested classes.

```
import random

class Account(object):
    num_accounts = 0
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
    self.name = name
    self.balance = balance
    Account.num_accounts += 1
def withdraw(self, amt):
    self.balance = self.balance - amt
def inquiry(self):
    return self.balance

class EvilAccount(Account):
def __init__(self,name,balance,evilfactor):
    Account.__init__(self,name,balance)
    self.evilfactor = evilfactor
def inquiry(self):
    if random.randint(0,4) == 1:
        return self.balance * self.evilfactor
    else:
        return self.balance

class MoreEvilAccount(EvilAccount):
    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.withdraw(5.00)
        EvilAccount.deposit(self,amount)

class WithdrawCharge(object):
    fee = 2.50
    def withdraw_fee(self):
        self.withdraw(self.fee)

class MostEvilAccount(EvilAccount, 
WithdrawCharge):
def withdraw(self,amt):
    self.withdraw_fee()
    super(MostEvilAccount,self).withdraw(amt)
```

And then I instantiate it all with

```
d = MostEvilAccount("Dave", 500.00, 1)
```

And everything is fine.  But when I try to call an inherited method:

```
d.withdraw(5.00)
```

I get recursion errors!

```
  File "StackO.py", line 37, in withdraw
   self.withdraw_fee()
  File "StackO.py", line 33, in withdraw_fee
    self.withdraw(self.fee)
  File "StackO.py", line 37, in withdraw
    self.withdraw_fee()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This is right out of Python Essential Reference by David M. Beazley, p121.

Why am I getting Recursion Errors?

Comment: `withdraw_fee` calls `withdraw`, which resolves to the most derived version which again calls `withdraw_fee`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `WithdrawCharge` doesn't actually have a method called `withdraw` on it. So, when you call it from `withdraw` on `MostEvilAccount`, Python has to search for an appropriate method, which is `withdraw` on `MostEvilAccount` as the `self` you passed into `WithdrawCharge.withdraw_fee` is a `MostEvilAccount`. To illustrate:

```
d = MostEvilAccount("Dave", 500.00, 1)
d.withdraw(5.00)

--> In MostEvilAccount.withdraw at line 37
----> In WithdrawCharge.withdraw_fee at line 33
------> In MostEvilAccount.withdraw at line 37
--------> In WithdrawCharge.withdraw_fee at line 33
```

and it continues...

There are a few ways you could go about fixing this. You could take the functionality of `WithdrawCharge` and embed it in `MostEvilAccount.withdraw`. You could also pass `Account.withdraw` in to `withdraw_fee` as an argument and have it call that.

Answer (score 0):

This error is here to prevent stack overflows. More info about how it works [here](http://pythonforengineers.com/python-prevents-infinite-recursion-hence-stack-overflow/)

Comment: It would be good if you can point to the OP where the recursion is happening